# Why am I keep getting WA for this solution for UVa 10511

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem, I think I have come up with a correct answer, but I am keep getting WA (wrong answer) response from the judge.

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1452

The problem distilled, is, given a 1 - * relationship between party and person, 1 - * relationship between person and club. Find a 1 - 1 relationship between person and club such that for all person related to a club, the number of persons belong to a any party is less than half of the number of club.

For example, let say we have

Person1 belongs to Party1 and Club1, Club2

Person2 belongs to Party2 and Club2, Club3

Person3 Belongs to Party3 and Club3, Club1

There are two assignments possible.

Person1 Club1

Person2 Club2

Person3 Club3

and

Person1 Club2

Person2 Club3

Person3 Club1

My idea is to model this problem as a maximum flow problem as follow:

For simplicity, let say there are two parties, four persons, and three clubs.

0 is the master source

1, 2 are the nodes representing the two parties

3, 4, 5, 6 are the nodes representing the four persons

7, 8, 9 are the nodes representing the three clubs.

10 is the master sink

master source connects to each party with capacity = (3 + 1)/2 - 1 = 1. That represents there can only be at most 1 person of 1 party representing in the council (or otherwise 2 will be equals to or more than half)

for each party person pair, have a link of capacity 1. That represents each person have only 1 party and used one seat in the previously allocated number.

for each person club pair, have a link of capacity 1. That represents each person can represent one club only.

Last but not least, all clubs goes to sink with capacity 1.

If the graph above has a maximum flow equals to the number of clubs - then there exist an assignment.

I can prove the design is correct as follow:

=>

If there exist a maximum flow of the size, each club node must be sending flow of value 1, implies each club node has exactly one person representing it. The representation respect the constraint of party participation as it has at most that many person in a party representing by the party node flow.

<=

If there is a representation, construct the flow as above, so that a flow exist. The flow is maximum because the maximal possible flow is constrainted by edge connecting to the sink.

So something must be wrong either with the arguments above, or with the implementation.

Without further ado, this is my source code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

// http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1452

// #define LOG

#include "UVa10511.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int UVa10511_assign_person_number(map<string, int>& person_numbers, map<int, string>& person_namings, string person_name);
int UVa10511_assign_party_number(map<string, int>& party_numbers, map<int, string>& party_namings, string party_name);
int UVa10511_assign_club_number(map<string, int>& club_numbers, map<int, string>& club_namings, string club_name);
int UVa10511_Edmonds_Karps(vector<vector<int>>& capacities, vector<vector<int>>& adjacency_list, int src, int dst);

int UVa10511()
{
    string line;
    int number_of_test_cases;
    cin >> number_of_test_cases;
    getline(cin, line); // consume the blank link after the number of test cases    
    getline(cin, line); // consume the blank link before the first test case
    for (int test_case = 0; test_case < number_of_test_cases; test_case++)
    {
        map<string, int> person_numbers;
        map<int, string> person_namings;
        map<string, int> party_numbers;
        map<int, string> party_namings;
        map<string, int> club_numbers;
        map<int, string> club_namings;

        vector<pair<int, int>> party_members;
        vector<pair<int, int>> person_clubs;

        while(getline(cin, line) && line != "" && line != " ")
        {
            string person_name;
            string party_name;
            string club_name;
            stringstream sin(line);
            sin >> person_name >> party_name;

            int person_id = UVa10511_assign_person_number(person_numbers, person_namings, person_name);
            int party_id = UVa10511_assign_party_number(party_numbers, party_namings, party_name);
            party_members.push_back(pair<int, int>(party_id, person_id));
            while(sin >> club_name)
            {
                int club_id = UVa10511_assign_club_number(club_numbers, club_namings, club_name);
                person_clubs.push_back(pair<int, int>(person_id, club_id));
            }   
        }

        int number_of_parties = party_numbers.size();
        int number_of_persons = person_numbers.size();
        int number_of_clubs = club_numbers.size();

        int number_of_nodes =
            /* master source */ 1 +
            /* parties       */ number_of_parties +
            /* person        */ number_of_persons +
            /* clubs         */ number_of_clubs +
            /* master sink   */ 1;

        vector<vector<int>> capacities;
        vector<vector<int>> adjacency_list;

        capacities.resize(number_of_nodes);
        adjacency_list.resize(number_of_nodes);

        for (int src = 0; src < number_of_nodes; src++)
        {
            capacities[src].resize(number_of_nodes);
            for (int dst = 0; dst < number_of_nodes; dst++)
            {
                capacities[src][dst] = 0;
            }
        }

        int max_party_participants = (number_of_clubs - 1) / 2; // Floor intended, not equal or more than half

        for (int p = 0; p < number_of_parties; p++)
        {
            int party_node = p + 1;
            capacities[0][party_node] = max_party_participants;
            adjacency_list[0].push_back(party_node);
            adjacency_list[party_node].push_back(0);
        }

        int person_node_start = 1 + number_of_parties;

        for (vector<pair<int, int>>::iterator pmi = party_members.begin(); pmi != party_members.end(); pmi++)
        {
            int party_id = pmi->first;
            int person_id = pmi->second;

            int party_node = party_id + 1;
            int person_node = person_node_start + person_id;

            capacities[party_node][person_node] = 1;
            adjacency_list[party_node].push_back(person_node);
            adjacency_list[person_node].push_back(party_node);
        }

        int club_node_start = 1 + number_of_parties + number_of_persons;
        for (vector<pair<int, int>>::iterator pci = person_clubs.begin(); pci != person_clubs.end(); pci++)
        {
            int person_id = pci->first;
            int club_id = pci->second;

            int person_node = person_node_start + person_id;
            int club_node = club_node_start + club_id;

            capacities[person_node][club_node] = 1;
            adjacency_list[person_node].push_back(club_node);
            adjacency_list[club_node].push_back(person_node);
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < number_of_clubs; c++)
        {
            int club_node = club_node_start + c;
            capacities[club_node][number_of_nodes - 1] = 1;
            adjacency_list[club_node].push_back(number_of_nodes - 1);
            adjacency_list[number_of_nodes - 1].push_back(club_node);
        }

#ifdef LOG
        cout << "digraph {" << endl;
        for (int src = 0; src < number_of_nodes; src++)
        {
            for (vector<int>::iterator di = adjacency_list[src].begin(); di != adjacency_list[src].end(); di++)
            {
                int dst = *di;
                cout << src << "->" << dst << " [label=\"" << capacities[src][dst] << "\"];" << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << "}" << endl;
#endif

        int total_flow = UVa10511_Edmonds_Karps(capacities, adjacency_list, 0, number_of_nodes - 1);

        if (test_case > 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (total_flow == number_of_clubs)
        {

            for (vector<pair<int, int>>::iterator pci = person_clubs.begin(); pci != person_clubs.end(); pci++)
            {
                int person_id = pci->first;
                int club_id = pci->second;

                int person_node = person_node_start + person_id;
                int club_node = club_node_start + club_id;

                if (capacities[person_node][club_node] == 0)
                {
                    cout << person_namings[person_id] << " " << club_namings[club_id] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Impossible." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int UVa10511_assign_party_number(map<string, int>& party_numbers, map<int, string>& party_namings, string party_name)
{
    int party_number;
    map<string, int>::iterator probe = party_numbers.find(party_name);
    if (probe == party_numbers.end())
    {
        party_number = party_numbers.size();
        party_numbers.insert(pair<string, int>(party_name, party_number));
        party_namings.insert(pair<int, string>(party_number, party_name));
    }
    else
    {
        party_number = probe->second;
    }

    return party_number;
}

int UVa10511_assign_person_number(map<string, int>& person_numbers, map<int, string>& person_namings, string person_name)
{
    int person_number;
    map<string, int>::iterator probe = person_numbers.find(person_name);
    if (probe == person_numbers.end())
    {
        person_number = person_numbers.size();
        person_numbers.insert(pair<string, int>(person_name, person_number));
        person_namings.insert(pair<int, string>(person_number, person_name));
    }
    else
    {
        person_number = probe->second;
    }

    return person_number;
}

int UVa10511_assign_club_number(map<string, int>& club_numbers, map<int, string>& club_namings, string club_name)
{
    int club_number;
    map<string, int>::iterator probe = club_numbers.find(club_name);
    if (probe == club_numbers.end())
    {
        club_number = club_numbers.size();
        club_numbers.insert(pair<string, int>(club_name, club_number));
        club_namings.insert(pair<int, string>(club_number, club_name));
    }
    else
    {
        club_number = probe->second;
    }

    return club_number;
}

int UVa10511_Edmonds_Karps(vector<vector<int>>& capacities, vector<vector<int>>& adjacency_list, int src, int dst)
{
    int total_flow = 0;
    // Step 2: Edmonds Karp's
    vector<int> parents; // Allow back-tracking the path found from bfs
    int number_of_nodes = capacities.size();
    parents.resize(number_of_nodes); // avoid reallocation
    while (true)
    {
        // Step 2.1: Use BFS to find an augmenting flow
        queue<int> bfs_queue;
        for (int n = 0; n < number_of_nodes; n++)
        {
            parents[n] = -1; // indicating the node is not enqueued
        }

        parents[src] = -2; // indicating the node is enqueued but no actual parent because this is the root
        bfs_queue.push(src);
        while (bfs_queue.size() > 0)
        {
            int current = bfs_queue.front();
            bfs_queue.pop();
            for (vector<int>::iterator ni = adjacency_list[current].begin(); ni != adjacency_list[current].end(); ni++)
            {
                int neighbor = *ni;
                if (parents[neighbor] == -1 && capacities[current][neighbor] > 0)
                {
                    parents[neighbor] = current;
                    bfs_queue.push(neighbor);

                    if (neighbor == dst)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (parents[dst] != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (parents[dst] == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // We have found an augmenting path, go through the path and find the max flow through this path
            int cur = dst;
            bool first = true;
            int max_flow_through_path = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                int src = parents[cur];
                if (src != -2)
                {
                    int dst = cur;
                    int available = capacities[src][dst];
#ifdef LOG
                    cout << src << "--" << available << "->" << dst << endl;
#endif
                    cur = parents[cur];
                    if (first)
                    {
                        max_flow_through_path = available;
                        first = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        max_flow_through_path = min(max_flow_through_path, available);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
#ifdef LOG
            cout << "flowing " << max_flow_through_path << endl << endl;
#endif
            total_flow += max_flow_through_path;
            // Flow the max flow through the augmenting path
            cur = dst;
            while (true)
            {
                int src = parents[cur];
                if (src != -2)
                {
                    capacities[src][cur] -= max_flow_through_path;
                    capacities[cur][src] += max_flow_through_path;
                    cur = parents[cur];
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return total_flow;
}
```

The source code is also posted in
https://github.com/cshung/Competition/blob/master/Competition/UVa10511.cpp

The same Edmonds Karps procedure is used to pass some other UVa problems, so I think it should be fine.

UVa820, UVa10480, UVa10779, UVa11506, UVa563 are all accepted with this Edmonds Karp procedure
(These code can be found in the Git repository as well)

I have even debugging the case where Edmond Karps make a wrong choice to being with a fixed it with an augmenting path for this test case

1

Person1 Party1 Club1 Club2

Person2 Party2 Club3

Person3 Party3 Club1

As my Edmond Karps used BFS in the adjacency list order, The chosen paths are

Master Source -> Party1 -> Person1 -> Club1 -> Master Sink

Master Source -> Party2 -> Person2 -> Club3 -> Master Sink

Master Source -> Party3 -> Person3 -> Club1 -> Person1 -> Club2 -> Master Sink [This used the reverse edge and proved going through reverse edge works]

Now I am really stuck, really don't know what's wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by this statement: *"the number of persons belong to a any party is less than half of the number of club"*. That seems to imply that you need at least 3 people in each club, and that those 3 people would need to be from different parties. With 1 person in a club, then 100% of the people are from the same party. With 2 people in a club, there are two parties with 50%. So 3 or more people must be in a club before less than half are from one party. What am I missing here?

Comment: When I paraphrased the problem says "the number of persons belong to a any party is less than half of the number of club", I mean "the number of persons **related to a club** belong to a any party is less than half of the number of club".

For example - if you have just 4 persons and 3 club. Like this:

Person1 Party1 Club1
Person2 Party2 Club2
Person3 Party3 Club3

The 1-1 relationship between Person and Club would be
Person1 Club1
Person2 Club2
Person3 Club3

Party1, 2 and 3 all have 1/3 participation (in the set of all persons related to a club)

I hope that clears the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking for this problem is correct, it is a typical problem that use maximum flow algorithm.

I have read your code over and over again, I can't find any mistake. Then I change the way you handle the input, then I got accept from UVA.

Just change the code

```
// you code 
cin >> number_of_test_cases;
getline(cin, line); // consume the blank link before the first test case
getline(cin, line); // consume the blank link before the first test case

//line 43
while(getline(cin, line) && line != "" && line != " ")

// change to
scanf("%d\n", &number_of_test_cases);

//line 43
// while(getline(cin, line) && line.length() > 0)
```

After change the code, I got accept from uva .

Hope get accept response from you.